# How to pass multiple strings in one function parameter in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I need to find a way to give multiple values to one parameter.

An example to explain what I want to achieve:

```
CREATE TABLE Students 
(
    code int,
    name varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO Students VALUES (1,'abc');
INSERT INTO Students VALUES (2,'def');
INSERT INTO Students VALUES (3,'ghi');
INSERT INTO Students VALUES (4,'jkl');

SELECT * FROM students;

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCount (@name VARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TheResultCount INT;  

    SELECT @TheResultCount = COUNT(*) 
    FROM Students 
    WHERE name IN (@name);

    RETURN @TheResultCount;
END;

SELECT dbo.GetCount('abc,def,ghi,jkl');
```

How do I achieve this requirement?

Comment: You can use `string_split` function. 
`...where name in (select * from string_split(@name,','))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `string_split` if you're using `SQL Server 2016` and later.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCount(@name VARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Students e
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM string_split(@name, ',') s
        WHERE s.value = e.name
    )
)
END
```

for older versions of `SQL Server` you can do this :

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCount(@name VARCHAR(8000)) 
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
RETURN ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Students e
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
            SELECT n.name 
            FROM (SELECT CAST(('<X>'+ REPLACE(@name,',' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') AS XML) Split ) s
            CROSS APPLY
            ( 
                SELECT d.s.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') as name 
                FROM s.Split.nodes('X') as d(s)
            ) n
    
        ) s
        WHERE s.name = e.name
    )
)
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing multiple values to a function really should use a table-valued parameter.

As an example you would have a suitably named table type defined:

```
create type NameList as table(Name Varchar(20));
```

And your function would use it like so:

```
create function dbo.GetCount (@Names NameList readonly) 
returns Int
as
begin
    return (select Count(*) from Students where name in (select name from @Names));
end;
```

And you would use the function like so:

```
declare @MyNames Namelist;
insert into @MyNames values('abc'), ('ghi')

select dbo.GetCount(@MyNames);
```

If however you really must pass a comma-delimited string, your function would look like:

```
create or alter function dbo.GetCount (@Names Varchar(max)) 
returns Int
as
begin
  return (
    select Count(*) from Students 
    where name in (select value from String_Split(@Names, ','))
  );
end;
```

Comment: A `primary key` on the TVP column would be wise. Also why not use a Table Valued Function?